# sql list actors who acted in a film before 1900 and also in a film after 2000

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, select

so I have 3 tables, actor(id, name), movie (id,name,year) and casts(aid, mid) (which are actor id and movie id). My goal is to select all the actors who acted in a film before 1900 and also in a film after 2000.
My query is

```
select a.id 
from actor a, movie m1, casts c1, movie m2, casts c2
where a.id = c1.aid = c2.aid and c1.mid = m1.id and c2.mid = m2.id and
m1.year >2000 and m2.year <1900;
```

this query took really long time and didnt seem to produce the right result.
So someone could please help me?

Comment: *My goal is to select all the actors who acted in a film before 1900 and also in a film after 2000* Does anybody live this long? You could probably optimize the query by returning nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the problem is the expression `a.id = c1.aid = c2.aid`. If I am not mistaken, this first compares `c1.aid` with `c2.aid` and then the boolean result with `a.id`.

You could try this:

```
select a.id 
from actor a
inner join casts c1 on c1.aid = a.id
inner join casts c2 on c2.aid = a.id
inner join movie m1 on c1.mid = m1.id
inner join movie m2 on c2.mid = m2.id 
where m1.year >2000 and m2.year <1900;
```

Or, if you better like the `where` syntax of inner joins, just change `a.id = c1.aid = c2.aid` to `a.id = c1.aid and a.id = c2.aid`

Answer (score 2):

To get actors who were in films during two date ranges, use two subqueries.  Something like this:

```
select yourFields
from yourTables
where actorId in (subquery to get actor id's for one date range)
and actorId in (subquery to get actor id's for second  date range)
```

You can work out the details.

Comment: can we do this without subquery? cuz we are not that far yet, so I guess there might be another way doing it

Comment: @Big_tboy Subqueries usually are easier to understand and maintain than joins. An often-stated reason to use joins instead would be to optimize for speed, but this is usually not a useful optimization in SQLite.

Answer (score 1):

This will also work

```
 

with first as (
SELECT Trim(mc.pid) as pid1
FROM   m_cast mc 
WHERE  Trim(mc.mid) IN (SELECT Trim(m.mid) 
                        FROM   movie m 
                        WHERE  Cast(Substr(Trim(m.year), -4) AS INTEGER) < 1970)
),
second as (
SELECT Trim(mc.pid) as pid2
FROM   m_cast mc 
WHERE  Trim(mc.mid) IN (SELECT Trim(m.mid) 
                        FROM   movie m 
                        WHERE  Cast(Substr(Trim(m.year), -4) AS INTEGER) > 1990) 
)
select first.pid1 from first intersect select second.pid2 from second
```

Answer (score 0):

This query likely takes a long time to run due to the size of the tables and large number of joins.

This query returns results because there are errors in the database.

The correct query is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a1.fname, a2.lname 
FROM 
-- Create the table used to get all movies before 1900
actor AS a1
INNER JOIN casts AS c1
ON a1.id=c1.pid
INNER JOIN movie as m1
on m1.id = c1.mid,
-- Create the table used to get all movies after 2000
actor as a2
INNER JOIN casts AS c2
ON a2.id=c2.pid
INNER JOIN movie as m2
on m2.id = c2.mid
-- Only display actors that have played before 1900 and after 2000
WHERE m1.year < 1900 AND m2.year > 2000 AND a1.id = a2.id;
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  The following url shows you how to format your answers to make them easier to read.  http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting.  After you read it, you can edit your answer so that the code is clearly code.  By the way, it wasn't me that downvoted your answer.

Comment: I believe you need to join a1 and a2.