# How to list movie actors who acted in every single film released in any given year

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two databases heading into this: a table acting_gigs with columns actor_name and movie_title and table movies with columns movie_title and release_year. I would like to make a SQL query that lists the names of all the actors that have participated in every single movie in a given release_year, and display two columns: the actors' names (actor_names) and the year in which they participated in every movie (release_year).

For example:

```
          movie_title          | release_year
    ------------------------------------------
    'The Green Mile'           | 2000
    'Titanic'                  | 1997
    'Cast Aways'               | 2000
    'Independence Day'         | 1997

          actor_name           | movie_title
    -------------------------------------------------
    'Leonardo DiCaprio'        | 'Titanic'
    'Tom Hanks'                | 'The Green Mile'
    'Will Smith'               | 'Independence Day'
    'Tom Hanks'                | 'Cast Aways'
```

Which means that the table I would like to return is

```
     actor_name | release_year
    ---------------------------
    'Tom Hanks' | 2000
```

I have been trying to use subqueries and outer joining, but I have not been able to quite arrive at a solution. I know that I have to use count, but I'm unsure how to apply it multiple times in a manner such as this.

Comment: This has been asked a few times. Possible duplicate of [sql list actors who acted in a film before 1900 and also in a film after 2000](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29617880/sql-list-actors-who-acted-in-a-film-before-1900-and-also-in-a-film-after-2000)

Comment: You tagged this in MySQL, SQL, PostgreSQL... Which one do you want?

Comment: Oh, my bad. I would like it in Postgre

Comment: @Jeffery Generally speaking, those posting a question should answer by upvoting or marking the answer as the correct answer... This is Q&A etiquette.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
SELECT y.actor_name, y.release_year
FROM (SELECT release_year, COUNT(*) AS cnt
      FROM movies
      GROUP BY release_year) AS x
INNER JOIN (SELECT actor_name, release_year, COUNT(*) AS cnt
            FROM acting_gigs AS t1
            INNER JOIN movies AS t2 ON t1.movie_title = t2.movie_title
            GROUP BY actor_name, release_year) AS y
ON x.release_year = y.release_year AND x.cnt = y.cnt
```

Derived table `x` contains the count of movies per year, whereas derived table `y` contains the count of movies per year / per actor.

The `JOIN` predicates:

- `x.release_year = y.release_year` and
- `x.cnt = y.cnt`

guarantee that, for a specific year, only actors that participated in *all movies of that year* are returned.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/efeae/5)

Here's another, probably more efficient, way using window functions:

```
SELECT DISTINCT actor_name, release_year
FROM (
SELECT actor_name, release_year,
       COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY actor_name, release_year) AS cntPerActorYear,
       COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY release_year) AS cntPerYear
FROM acting_gigs AS t1
INNER JOIN movies AS t2 ON t1.movie_title = t2.movie_title ) AS t
WHERE cntPerActorYear = cntPerYear
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/efeae/8)

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
select m.release_year
     , a.actor_name
     , count(1) total_movies
from movies m
    join actors a on a.movie_title = m.movie_title
group by m.release_year, a.actor_name
order by m.release_year, a.actor_name -- or however you want to order it
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's how you do it in MS SQL - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/492ac/3

```
SELECT
  A.ActorName,
  M.ReleaseYear
FROM
  Movies AS M
INNER JOIN
  ActorsMovies AS A
ON
  M.MovieTitle = A.MovieTitle
```